# Ways to send header key with get/post in angular to express4 rest api

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am using Basic Authentication header to secure our service. The service is tested in rest client that works properly. Now we want to send the key from UI part. But we are unable to send the header value with get and post calls.

//JSON variable that contain the header authentication key.

```
var authorizationHeader = {
    headers:  {'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
};
```

//The controller that is used to send the request and receive the value.

```
app.controller("UserAuth",function($scope,$http){
    $http.get(getAuthorization,authorizationHeader).success(function(data) {
        var data=data;
    }):
});
```

In rest api, we receive the header as:

```
var headervalue=req.headers.Authorization;
```

But we receive the value `undefined`. Please identify my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

you can use $httpProvider interceptor, please check the document [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

basically you will need to create a service as interceptor, the code will be like :

```
app.factory('authInterceptorService' function(){
   var _request = function(config){
       var authToken = myTokenService.getToken();//this will be your service to get authToken
       config.headers.Authorization='Basic '+authToken;
     }

   return {
      request:_request
   }

});
```

then in your app config you can add the interceptor in this way

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
});
```

then every time you use $http, the auth token will be added into the request header